# Set a 10-second timer for each subject input

Tags: javascript, html

I've been making a typing game at school. The time setting does not work.
A time limit of 10 seconds is attached to each subject. When one subject is finished, the time will be reset to 10 seconds again.Please give me some advice.

1,The user sees the subject text, types the same value into the text box, and presses the OK button.

2,When the OK button is pressed, clear the text box and display the next subject.

3,Repeat steps 1 and 2 5 times.

4,When the ok button is pressed the 5th time, the total number of characters from the 1st to the 5th times, in which the subject and the value entered by the user are incorrect, is displayed on the screen.

⚠️If the OK button is not pressed within 10 seconds, it is an error for the number of characters in the subject.

Comment: And the problem/question is? And what have you tried so far to solve this problem on your own?

Comment: @Andreas i think you do him wrong here. He described it rather well. The question is how he can reset the timer. It's the second sentence... also he did post all of his code even so he did not show what he tried so far. So tbh i think, for a first time question it is rather well formulated.

Comment: @JustAMicrobe First question or not... _""It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_. _"did post all of his code"_ - OP is supposed to post a [mcve] not just dump everything and expect us to dig through it. _"did not show what he tried so far"_ which is a crucial part of a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Andreas yes you are correct, but obviously he is new. Instead of just telling him "problem? what have you tried so far", which kinda does sound pretty rude, write him what you did write to me. That you should formulate the Question in the title, post a minimal reproducible example and so on.

Comment: @Andreas it is true that the question is not of good quality. However, OP did show what their problem is (although poorly worded and hard to identify on first sight, unless you read hard through the lines and dig into their code). Also, they did show what they tried so far, because they literally posted their current code, as is. This is not a question that is valuable to SO all-too-much in the end, as I doubt anyone will ever face this exact same issue as OP, so it doesnt hurt to just be nice to them and turn a blind eye to the post quality. Thats my humble opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the TIME in your init function:

```js
function init() {
  
  question =
    questionList[Math.floor(Math.random() * questionList.length)];
  subject.textContent = question["text"];
  index = 0;   
  TIME = 10;
  input.value = '';
  input.focus();
}
```

Otherwise the time will just keep on running.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7k928Lw/1/) to try it out.
But you have several other issues: When you misspelled and try to correct yourself within the time, you can not do this. The input is blocked. And you should set the cursor inside of your input when you load the page, or only start the timer when somebody starts typing. otherwise it is really hard to do it in time.

Answer (score 3):

I left some clarifications as code comments

```js
const subject = document.getElementById("subject");
const timer = document.getElementById("timer");
const input = document.getElementById("text");
const questionList = [
  { text: "Hello", pronunciation: "Hello" },
  { text: "World", pronunciation: "World" },
  { text: "HTML", pronunciation: "HTML" },
  { text: "CSS", pronunciation: "CSS" },
  { text: "PHP", pronunciation: "PHP" },
];

var question =
  questionList[Math.floor(Math.random() * questionList.length)];
subject.textContent = question["text"];
var TIME = 10;
var index = 0;    
var CorrectCount = 0;
var missTypeCount = 0;
var state;


const countdown = setInterval(function () {
  
  if (TIME > 0) {
   
    timer.textContent = "Time limit：" + --TIME;
  } 
  if (TIME === 0) {
    
    finish();
  }

}, 1000);



document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {

  if (e.key === question["pronunciation"].charAt(index) ) {

    index++;
  
    if (index == question["pronunciation"].length ) {
      // Here is where a full correct word was completely written.
      // Normally here is where you want to increment CorrectCount++ and reset TIME = 10
      // However this is redundant, because you are performing these actions on check()
      // I would advice to either keep this conditional, or the check() function, not both
      CorrectCount;
      
    }
  } else {

    missTypeCount++;
    
    e.preventDefault(); 

  }
});


function check() {

  if(input.value === subject.textContent  ) {
 
    CorrectCount++;
    
    init();
  } 
  if (CorrectCount >= 5 ) {
   
    
    finish();
 }
}



function init() {
  
  question =
    questionList[Math.floor(Math.random() * questionList.length)];
  subject.textContent = question["text"];
  index = 0;   
  input.value = '';
  input.focus();
  // You need to set/reset the time to 10 here
  TIME = 10;
}



function finish() {
  clearInterval(countdown);
  
  if (missTypeCount >= 0 ){
    subject.textContent="Perfect"
  }
  // these conditionals are not doing what you want them to do.
  // I believe you mean missTypeCount >= 1 && missTypeCount <= 3
  if (missTypeCount >= 1 || missTypeCount >= 3 ){
    subject.textContent="Good"
  }
  if (missTypeCount >= 4 || missTypeCount >= 8 ){
    subject.textContent="Almost"
  }
  if (missTypeCount >= 9 ){
    subject.textContent="Bad"
  }
  

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   
      <div>
        <div class="subject"><h1 id="subject"></h1></div>
        
  
    <form name="typing"  onsubmit="return false;">

      <div class="text">
     <input id="text" type="text" autocomplete="off" >
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
     <input  type="submit" value="ok"  onclick="check();" >
    </div>

    </form>

    <div class="timer">
      <p id="timer">Time limit ：10</p>
    </div>

</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: >> ( I would advice to either keep this conditional, or the check() function, not both  )                 I fixed the code. I believe this code is complete. Please give me some advice

Comment: I would suggest to put `TIME = 10` inside of your `init()` function

Comment: Succeeded. Thank you for your support

Answer (score -3):

Use the php function time() or try something like that

```
<script> 
      var myVar;
      var timer = document.getElementById("userInput");
      var countDownSeconds;
      function startTime(){ 
        myVar = setInterval(start, 1000);
        document.getElementById("timerr").innerHTML = timer.value;
        countDownSeconds = timer.value;
      } 

      function start(){
        countDownSeconds--;
        document.getElementById("timerr").innerHTML = countDownSeconds;
        if (countDownSeconds == -1){
          stop();
          document.getElementById("timerr").innerHTML = "0";  
        }
      }

      function stop(){
        clearInterval(myVar);
      }
    </script>
```